# How to find a node in a binary search tree

Tags: java

I was reading about binary trees in java. I found this code :

```
public BSTNode findNode(Comparable val){
        int delta = val.compareTo(value);
        // the value is less than this.value
        if(delta < 0){
            // if there is a leftChild, return left.findNode(val)
            // there is no leftChild, so the val does not exist
            // in the node, so return null
            return (left!= null)? left.findNode(val): null;
        }
        // else if the value is greater than this.value
        else if (delta > 0){
            // if there is a rightChild, then return right.findNode(val)
            // else, there is no rightChild, return null
            return (right != null)? right.findNode(val): null;
        }
        // else, dela == 0, so we have found the node with that
        // val, return the node
        return this;
    }
```

I do not understand how this works :

```
return (left!= null)? left.findNode(val): null;
return (right != null)? right.findNode(val): null;
```

Can you rewrite it in another way?

Thanks

Comment: What don't you understand? The ternary condition operator or recursion?

Comment: the both lines : `return (left!= null)? left.findNode(val): null;`
`return (right != null)? right.findNode(val): null;` I do not know how they work

Comment: Java ternary operator: http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018

Comment: @Eran there is no recursion in this code , isn't it ? Thanks

Comment: @Joe left.findNode(val) is a recursive call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's go step by step. First of all, I'll focus on the algorithm itself.

```
class Node<T> {
    T value;
    Node left;
    Node right;
}
```

You are guaranteed that all values to the `left` are smaller or equal than `value` and all values to the `right` are larger or equal than `value`. This makes searching easier. If you're looking for element `val` you simply compare it to the `value` in current `Node`. If desired element is equal current element, you've found it. If it's greater it can only be in the right part of a tree. Otherwise in the left side.

It can happen that the element isn't here. It happens if you see that it should be to the left/right from the current node, but there is nothing there (`null`).

So the `BinaryTreeSearch` is:

```
T search(Node tree, T val) {
    int delta = tree.getValue.compareTo(val);
    if (delta == 0) {
        return tree.getValue;
    } else if (delta > 0) {
        return search(tree.getRight(), val);
    } else {
        return search(tree.getLeft(), val);
    }
}
```

But wait... this leads to the NPE if the item isn't here.
Let's modify it:

```
T search(Node tree, T val) {
    if (tree == null)
         return null;
    int delta = tree.getValue.compareTo(val);
    if (delta == 0) {
        return tree.getValue;
    } else if (delta > 0) {
        return search(tree.getRight(), val);
    } else {
        return search(tree.getLeft(), val);
    }
}
```

This can be also rewritten this way:

```
T search(Node tree, T val) {
    int delta = tree.getValue.compareTo(val);
    if (delta == 0) {
        return tree.getValue;
    } else if (delta > 0) {
        if (tree.getRight() == null) 
            return null;
        return search(tree.getRight(), val);
    } else {
        if (tree.getLeft() == null)
            return null;
        return search(tree.getLeft(), val);
    }
}
```

But here comes the ternary operator which is shortened and simplified `if-else`.

```
result = testCondition ? value1 : value2
```

which is the same as

```
if (testCondition) {
    result = value1;
} else {
    result = value2;
}
```

> Another conditional operator is ?:, which can be thought of as shorthand for an if-then-else statement (discussed in the Control Flow Statements section of this lesson). This operator is also known as the ternary operator because it uses three operands. In the following example, this operator should be read as: "If someCondition is true, assign the value of value1 to result. Otherwise, assign the value of value2 to result."

So we finally receive:

```
T search(Node tree, T val) {
    int delta = tree.getValue.compareTo(val);
    if (delta == 0) {
        return tree.getValue;
    } else if (delta > 0) {
        return (tree.getRight() == null) ? null : search(tree.getRight(), val);
    } else {
        return (tree.getLeft() == null) ? null : search(tree.getLeft(), val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They can be rewritten as:

```
if(left != null) {
  return left.findNode(val);
} else {
  return null;
}
```

and

```
if(right != null) {
  return right.findNode(val);
} else {
  return null;
}
```

Hope this helps :-).